# How can you move a list from Excel to Sage?

Tags: plot, modeling

I have a column in Excel, which I need to move from Excel to Sage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) to open the offending Excel file on Linux
2. save column to text file
3. open text file in Sage (see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/sage-support/browse_thread/thread/4600e491955f4960) for details about opening text files in Sage)

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily. Sage runs on Linux Excel does not. Your best bet would be to write a python script to export the list to a file then import that into excel after downloading it from the Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Sage is python application, install a module for reading xml files (there are some) and there you go ...